# What is the proof for this graph energy

Tags: graph-theory

Good day mathematians.

I am working on graph energy, on a  topological index called inverse sum indeg of neighbor degree sum energy of graphs. In the course of my research I obtained a corrolary that goes as follows:
"Let $n$ be the number of vertices in a complete graph $G$, $E(G)=n(n-1)^2$" where E(G) is the energy of the graph $G$ and is obtained by summing all the eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix of G together. I'm having quite a difficult time proving this corrolary of mine. I don't know if anybody can help.
Below is my attempt of the proof which I surely believe is lacking something.

Proof:
Let $n$ be the number of vertices in a complete graph then $E(G)=\sum^{n}_{i=1}|\lambda_i|$
$E(G)=\sum^{n}_{i=1}|\lambda_i|=n(n-1)^2$
$\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{i=1}|\lambda_i|=(n-1)^2$
Let $\sum^{n}_{i=1}|\lambda_i|=Q$ so that
$\frac{1}{\frac{\frac{n}{2}}{Q}+\frac{\frac{n}{2}}{Q}}=\frac{1}{n}Q=(n-1)^2$,
$\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}Q}=n-1$,
$\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}Q}+1=n$,
Equality is true for all $n>1$ hence
$E(G)=n(n-1)^2$

Comment: If $E(G) = \sum |\lambda_i|$, then $E(K_n) = 2n-2$. It is well-known that the spectrum of $K_n$ is $(n-1)$ with algebraic multiplicity $1$, and $(-1)$ with algebraic multiplicity $(n-1)$.

Comment: Does this prove the equality above? Or is an addition to what my proof should contain?

Comment: You claim that $E(K_n) = n(n-1)^2$, unless I misunderstood what you wrote. This is false, as $n(n-1)^2 \neq 2n-2$.